# как менять только параметр QBrush в QGraphicsScene::addEllipse

Tags: c++, qt, графика

При выполнении код съедает память как менять только параметр `QBrush`?

```cpp
if(link2 == 0) {
    scene2->addEllipse(100, 395, radius1, radius1, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::red));
}
if(link2 == 1) {
    scene2->addEllipse(100, 395, radius1, radius1, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::green));
}
```

`link2` изменяется по таймеру

Comment: Мне кажется, вы копаете не туда. Из обрывочной последней фразы вашего вопроса я подозреваю, что вам надо менять цвет добавленного эллипса, а не добавлять каждый раз новый. Тогда видимо и память "съедаться" не будет

Comment: Совершенно верно. Я хочу менять только цвет в QBrush не добавляя новый addEllipse

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

```
// где-нибудь в полях класса положим указатель на эллипс
QGraphicsEllipseItem* ellipse; 

// один раз добавим эллипс на сцену и запомним указатель на добавленный объект
this->ellipse = scene2->addEllipse(100, 395, radius1, radius1, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::red));

// а теперь при срабатывании какого-то события просто поменяем эллипсу цвет
if(link2 == 0) {
   this->ellipse->setBrush(Qt::red);
}
else if(link2 == 1) {
   this->ellipse->setBrush(Qt::green);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, но меняет цвет последнее условие // универсальная процедура индикации
void MainWindow::indicate(quint16 X, quint16 Y, quint8 deltaY, quint8 posNum, quint8 radius, const QColor color) {

    this->ellipse = scene->addEllipse(X, Y + deltaY * posNum, radius, radius, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(color));
}